# Magento Database Flat Table

Tags: php, database, magento

I have a common question about Magento Database,

In magento there are some flat tables which are updated simultaneously when DML is performed on related table, these flat table are only readable,

If so why magento team did not use views instead of flat table

Answer (score 4):

While Magento is commonly run on relational database technology like MySQL, it stores its data as an EAV database. The kajiggery-pokery necessary to retrieve data stored in this manner is probably anathema to setting up views. You need a large quantity of self-joins to convert rows back into the columnar storage you are used to having in a relational database.

The usual age-old method of speeding up EAV data retrieval is to pull it out and store it in a flat file.